# C# cast issue - brevity

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry for the crappy question title.
Is there a way to do this on one line:

```
Button button = (Button)Gridview.Cells[0].FindControl("controlname");
button.Enabled = (some boolean);
```

For example, a directcast in vb will allow:

```
DirectCast(Gridview.Cells(0).FindControl("controlname"), Button).Enabled = (some boolean value)
```

Or does it need to be on two lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you tried the obvious but got caught out by binding priority. The methods and properties will be done before the cast unless specified otherwise. Using parentheses you can make it do the cast first and then call the property on the now cast control.

```
((Button)Gridview.Cells[0].FindControl("controlname")).Enabled = (some boolean);
```

Comment: @KirkWoll: In england (or at least where I was taught) `()` are called brackets as well as parentheses (I believe some people call them braces). I would normally refer to them as just brackets (as shown here), differentiating them from other types by calling the otehrs square brackets, curly brackets, etc. Wikipedia tells me "Used unqualified, brackets refer to different types of brackets in different parts of the world and in different contexts." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: @KirkWoll: According to [this](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=155474&idForum=1&lp=ende&lang=de) discussion they are called brackets by quite a few native speakers.

Comment: Updated to parentheses now for internationali(s|z)ation. :)

Comment: @Chris, "brackets" is the superset of all three pairs: `()`, `{}`, `[]` -- all of which have independent meaning in C#.  In other words, it's also accurate to also call them "tokens" and "characters", but not as precise.

Comment: @KirkWoll: they key part is "Used unqualified, brackets refer to different types of brackets in different parts of the world and in different contexts." They are all types of brackets but here if I say brackets on its own it means specifially `()`. Apparently (so the net tells me) in america brackets on its own means `[]`. It was a fair call though. I have to admit that I'd never realised there was this difference before so thanks for flagging it to my attention. I can be more precise next time. :)

Answer (score 6):

Just enclose your original expression in parenthesis:

```
((Button)Gridview.Cells[0].FindControl("controlname")).Enabled = true;
```

Comment: why did somebody -1 this for just being 30 seconds slower than my response? Seems a bit harsh!

Comment: Your response did not appear on my page until after I had posted mine. And when it did first appear, it had no explanatory text. Good 'ol SO quick-draw...and modify

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand since I saw the timestamps on it after my edit to add explanation. I am 100% sure that you didn't copy or anything which is why I was so surprised that somebody -1ed you and hoped that the down voter might explain or retract the down vote (I can only assume it was for duplicating but who knows).

Comment: I'm going to accept the first posted answer, but I gave you an upvote. Thanks.